# What is the best practice when writing a li tag

Tags: html, semantic-markup

### Best Practice When Writing `<li>` Tags

My question is when you have a `<li>` tag which states the definition of words , like

```
<li>
    markup language - a set of tags and/or a set of rules for creating tags that
    can be embedded in digital text to provide additional information about the
    text in order to facilitate automated processing of it, including editing and
    formatting for display or printing.
</li>
```

Should that definition be inside a `<p>` tag or is it fine the way it is?

And my last question is, should my `<li>` tag be written on a single line?

```
<li>dog - a domestic mammal that that can be a variety of breeds</li>
```

Or, with line breaks?

```
<li>
dog - a domestic mammal that that can be a variety of breeds
</li>
```

Comment: You should reformat this to include exactly the code you're asking about. What are these lines with 'li' for?

Comment: It doesn't matter at all, this is just a code formatting issue and not a problem with the webpage. You will get the same result with the 3 versions. If you want to show breakline in the site, you should add </p> or <br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML has specific tags for [definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) (`dl`, `dt`, `dd`), which you could use instead.  If you're asking about the syntax specifically, it doesn't really matter, as long as you're consistent and keeping up with your current code's standards.

Furthermore, your choice to use a nested `p` tag depends on the amount of content and styling you need for the definition, there's no one single "best practice."

Comment: It would be a pretty old browser that didn't support the `d*` elements. They've been around since HTML 4.01

Comment: Actually `dl` has been in HTML from the very beginning (HTML 2.0 and even earlier informal descriptions, from the early 1990s).

Answer (score 0):

li tags should always be inside a ol (Order list, numbered list) or ul (unordered list, bulleted list) tag.

1. Entry 1
2. Entry 2

```
<ol>
<li>Entry 1</li>
<li>Entry 2</li>
</ol>
```

or

- Entry 1
- Entry 2

```
<ul>
<li>Entry 1</li>
<li>Entry 2</li>
</ul>
```

Also there is a different tag for definitions.

Answer (score 0):

i'd like to use single line as you meant as if it were has just small contents:

```
<ol>
   <li>member 9</li>
   <li>member 3</li>
   <li>member 7</li>
</ol>
```